# No img displayed on the leaflet control

Tags: leaflet

My web app contains two basemaps to display. I created a leaflet control layer to manage their visibility :

```
var baseMaps = {
     "Bing Satellite": bingLayer,
      "OpenCycleMap": tileLayer
};

L.control.layers(baseMaps).addTo(map);
```

The issue is the icon which should be within the control doesn't show up. When I inspect, the console renders a 404 error : `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` on **layers-2px.png**.
I'm using cdn to call leaflet so I have no clue about the issue!!

Here is the rendering in the map :

[image]

Your assistance would be appreciated.

I put a working example.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>Leaflet Control.Layers</title>
  <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />

    <!-- Load Leaflet from CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA=="
    crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-nMMmRyTVoLYqjP9hrbed9S+FzjZHW5gY1TWCHA5ckwXZBadntCNs8kEqAWdrb9O7rxbCaA4lKTIWjDXZxflOcA=="
    crossorigin=""></script>


    <!-- Load Esri Leaflet from CDN -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet@2.2.3/dist/esri-leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-YZ6b5bXRVwipfqul5krehD9qlbJzc6KOGXYsDjU9HHXW2gK57xmWl2gU6nAegiErAqFXhygKIsWPKbjLPXVb2g=="
    crossorigin=""></script>


  <style>
    body { margin:0; padding:0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  var gray = L.layerGroup();

  // more than one service can be grouped together and passed to the control together
  L.esri.basemapLayer("DarkGray").addTo(gray);
  L.esri.basemapLayer("GrayLabels").addTo(gray);

  var states = L.esri.featureLayer({
      url: "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/3",
      style: function (feature) {
          return {color: '#bada55', weight: 2 };
      }
  });

  var map = L.map('map', {
      center: [39, -97.5],
      zoom: 4,
      layers: [gray, states]
  });

  var baseLayers = {
      "Grayscale": gray,
      "Streetmap": L.esri.basemapLayer("Streets")
  };

  var overlays = {
      "U.S. States": states
  };

  // http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#control-layers
  L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I edited my auestion

Comment: I see no problem. No error is displayed

Comment: This is what going to drive me crazy.  I reproduce the same thing in local and it works fine,  yet when I work directly in our remote server it renders me this 404 error on the icon.

Comment: my question is,  Can I force to put a custom icon to the control?

Comment: Ok, so you want to replace [this](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/dist/images/layers-2x.png) with a custom icon. Correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the background-image property of the following css selectors by setting your custom image:

```
.leaflet-control-layers-toggle, .leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
    background-image: url('http://ovrdc.github.io/parcel-viewer/assets/images/layers-bl.png');
    background-size: 80%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>Leaflet Control.Layers</title>
  <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />

    <!-- Load Leaflet from CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA=="
    crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-nMMmRyTVoLYqjP9hrbed9S+FzjZHW5gY1TWCHA5ckwXZBadntCNs8kEqAWdrb9O7rxbCaA4lKTIWjDXZxflOcA=="
    crossorigin=""></script>


    <!-- Load Esri Leaflet from CDN -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet@2.2.3/dist/esri-leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-YZ6b5bXRVwipfqul5krehD9qlbJzc6KOGXYsDjU9HHXW2gK57xmWl2gU6nAegiErAqFXhygKIsWPKbjLPXVb2g=="
    crossorigin=""></script>


  <style>
    body { margin:0; padding:0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0; }
    .leaflet-control-layers-toggle, .leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
      background-image: url('http://ovrdc.github.io/parcel-viewer/assets/images/layers-bl.png');
      background-size: 80%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  var gray = L.layerGroup();

  // more than one service can be grouped together and passed to the control together
  L.esri.basemapLayer("DarkGray").addTo(gray);
  L.esri.basemapLayer("GrayLabels").addTo(gray);

  var states = L.esri.featureLayer({
      url: "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/3",
      style: function (feature) {
          return {color: '#bada55', weight: 2 };
      }
  });

  var map = L.map('map', {
      center: [39, -97.5],
      zoom: 4,
      layers: [gray, states]
  });

  var baseLayers = {
      "Grayscale": gray,
      "Streetmap": L.esri.basemapLayer("Streets")
  };

  var overlays = {
      "U.S. States": states
  };

  // http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#control-layers 
  L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```